# How to manipulate DOM after new elements have been inserted?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dom, woocommerce

I am working on a WooCommerce/WordPress site at the moment and on the checkout page, when I submit the form, it submits through Ajax and if there are errors (required fields not filled in etc), the page inserts some html and lists what fields need to be filled in.

I have some jQuery that places this newly inserted html in the page to a new place on the page but it doesn't work.

**WooCommerce code inserted on submit (if errors):**

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error">
    <li><strong>First Name</strong> is a required field.</li>
</ul>
```

**My Code:**

```
var wc_errors = jQuery('ul.woocommerce-error');
jQuery('.errors_placeholder').append(wc_errors);
```

It might be useful also to note that my JavaScript file is loaded before the WooCommerce JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wc_errors = $('ul.woocommerce-error');
    $('.errors_placeholder').appendTo(wc_errors);    
});
```

You need it in the $(document).ready function to tell jQuery the DOM is ready.

Check out my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/TBDev/)

Comment: I do have that mate, my code was only a snippet of my custom JavaScript file. 

I don't think you understand my problem. You see, when the page is loaded, the DOM has loaded and once the form is submitted, the page loads NEW DOM elements, so my code that has already RAN, doesnt affect the newly inserted code.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done using `checkout_error` event.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document.body).on('checkout_error', function (error_message) {
        $('.errors_placeholder').empty().html(error_message);
    });
})(jQuery);
```